# Django 'x' object has no attribute 'get_form'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a generic DetailView and I'm trying to do a form for the comment of an user after I display the details of the model but I keep getting the error  'ProductFeedbackView' object has no attribute 'get_form'.

I don't know if the templates have any problem because the error is in the view when I try to get the form into a variable.

Here is comment's model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,)

    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=True)
    ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-feedback', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment's form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']
```

View:

```
class ProductFeedbackView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'services/product-feedback.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('product-feedback', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'content': self.object})
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls's:

```
    ...
    path('feedback/<int:pk>/', ProductFeedbackView.as_view(), name='product-feedback'),
```

Template:

```
<a href="{% url 'product-detail' product.id %}">Details</a>
<a href="{% url 'product-feedback' product.id %}">Feedback</a>

<p>{{ product.author }}</p>
<h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ product.description }}</p>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="POST">
        <label for="comment">Type comment</label>
        {{ form.as_p }} {% csrf_token %} <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}

{% for comment in comment.service.all %}
     <p>{{ comment.author }}</p>
     <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    ...

    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: And can you post the traceback ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit the form view mixing like so:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormMixin

class ProductFeedbackView(DetailView, FormMixin):
    ...
```

As per django classy class based views guide:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/

However, mixing a detail view and an edit view probably doesn't match the usual djagno-esque methodology.

Youre likely better off having a detail view and an edit view (FormView) respectively and using the built in behaviour of django.

Just add an edit button to your detail page which is a reverse to the form view :)

If you need more help, just ping a comment.

Comment: I'm not being able to render the comments bellow the form.
I tried doing this:

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    context = {'comments' : comments}
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = CommentForm(initial={'content': self.object})
    return context


{% for comment in comments %}
    <div>
         <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
          <p>{{ comment.content|linebreaks }}</p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}

The product model has no relation to the comment, it is the comment that has the forkey.

Comment: I prefer to have the form in the same page as the details of the product, I don't want to redirect the user to another page only for the comment, I would prefer the app to have a small amount of pages.

Comment: A form view automatically adds the form to the context as the context object `form`

Comment: Then in this case you can use the form mixin class :) I updated my answer

Comment: I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.views.mixins'

Comment: Sorry, thats my error, see updated import

Comment: I still only have the form rendering.
I think the problem is in the {% for comment in comment.service.all %}<p>{{ comment.author }}</p><p>{{ comment.content }}</p>{% endfor %}

The rest is equal to the code in the post and in your answer...

Comment: Are you missing the initial data? E.g. the data already saved?

Comment: I don't think so.
This part is the only one that isn't working. {% for comment in comment.service.all %}<p>{{ comment.author }}</p><p>{{ comment.content }}</p>{% endfor %}
I don't know if it is because of the comment or comment.service.all...

Comment: Can you show you `Service` model?

Comment: Product model:
class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

Comment: Add it to the question please, sorry, not as a comment

Comment: It's now edited.